# asp.net store roles in session Roles.AddUsertoRole (not what i'm looking for?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

This is a weird way to state the question, but this is what I'm trying to achieve.

This is what I'm doing

Connect to a MySQL Db(complete)
authenticate(complete)
select all the roles that I have specified in mySQL  (complete)
store those roles somehow so I can display controls and links based on their role membership.

I just got this figured out to handle the mySQL part in web.config

```
system.web
    membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider" /
roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider" /
/system.web
```

I'm using this as code

```
MySqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    string roleName = dr2["role"].ToString();
                    //error here -> Roles.AddUserToRole(userID, roleName);
                }
```

Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Is Roles.AddUserToRole really what i'm looking for to satisfy my needs.  I think I need to store the user roles in the sessio don't I?  I

Answer (score 0):

*Is Roles.AddUserToRole really what i'm looking for to satisfy my needs. I think I need to store the user roles in the sessio don't I?*

NO! Adding user to roles means the provider will link the user to the role. As you already have the user linked, this is a worthless direction.

*store those roles somehow so I can display controls and links based on their role membership*

Why do you need to do this? At the page level, you can set up ASP.NET security with trimmings so you can automagically exclude pages from the user's view if they are not in the correct role(s). As far as sections/controls/etc, you can check to see if a user IS in a role and then determine whether or not to display it. If you use sections, a lot of this can be done declaratively rather than programmatically.

The one caveat is what your membership provider supports. The "out of the box" providers (Access and SQL Server) support security trimmings and declarative syntax for exclusions of sections of a page, etc. If the MySQL provider full implements all of the methods, you should be fine using it, as well. If you create a custom provider, there are certain parts YOU have to implement to get things to work.

The short story is once you grab a membershipUser (authenticate the person), you will have access to whether the person is in role or not. This is all part of the standard implementation of a membership provider in .NET. As long as the provider you are using for MySQL covers all of the same methods, you can do a quick google search and find tons of sites showing how to show/hide bits based on roles.

Comment: i guess thats the part i'm confused on, because what I have is a table with user and roles, and those roles are in the table, when i have those roles selected, how do i make sure asp.net uses those roles

Comment: also, my users cna have like 1-20 roles

Comment: how do i tell asp.net that user x is apart of the InfoAdmin role?

Comment: does my questions even make sense