# how to add mysql roles to RoleManager

Tags: asp.net, mysql

Is there a good example, on how once I validate a user I can add Roles to that user.  The roles come from a stored procedure on a mysql db.  I need to be able to add multiple roles for a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add new roles to your Roles
Something like

```
 if (!Roles.RoleExists("TestRole"))
 {
     Roles.CreateRole("TestRole");
 }
```

And then add that role to your user

```
  Roles.AddUserToRole("TestUser", "TestRole");
```

You have to add role before you can assign it to a user

Comment: please see this posting, i wa stold thats completely wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083708/asp-net-store-roles-in-session-roles-addusertorole-not-what-im-looking-for

Comment: Why you are using a separate table to store your roles, why can't you use the default role store?

Comment: because i need to have like 15-20 custom roles and a user can belong to 1-20 of them, and each role services a different function, and i'm also not sure what you mean by default role store

Comment: To add multiple roles you may use `Roles.AddUserToRoles(username,string[] roleNames)`, By default role store I mean the table you configured to be used by your role manager

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like the [Roles.AddUserToRoles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertoroles.aspx) Method?

Comment: well i thought i ment that but see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083708/asp-net-store-roles-in-session-roles-addusertorole-not-what-im-looking-for  That idea of mine got totally blew up...

Comment: Maybe you mean User.IsInRole to test if the user is in the role already, then?

Comment: they are none in the "role" because i havent added them to asp.net roles, so i cant check against them, my roles in my mysql are custom

Comment: So, you have two options.  1) Add your custom roles to the SqlRoleManager and then add them to users and check them as suggested.  2) Write your own code to check for roles (either a custom RoleManager, or some other implementation)

Comment: how do you use a SqlRoleManager for MySQL, i wish there was a easy guide for RoleManager for mysql

Comment: Aha, I totally missed that you were using MySQL.  This CodeProject project seems to have good feedback: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx